# GLSL 2.0 attribute question

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader

What does the [] operator do when addressing an attribute vec4?

```
attribute vec4 a_MatrixWeights;
...
foo(float weight);
...

void main()
{
  foo(a_MatrixWeights[0]);
  foo(a_MatrixWeights[1]);
  foo(a_MatrixWeights[2]);
  foo(a_MatrixWeights[3]);
}
```

Is this addressing the individual fields of the vec4 (.x, .y, .z, .w) or is this somehow treating the vec4 and an array of vec4 and doing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's for accessing individual fields.

> Array subscripting syntax can also be
>   applied to vectors to provide numeric
>   indexing. So in vec4 pos; pos[2]
>   refers to the third element of pos and
>   is equivalent to pos.z [GLSL spec 1.20.8, 5.5 Vector Components]

Also array subscripting can be use for accessing colums of matrices:

```
mat4 m;
vec4 c = m[1]; // access the second column of m
```

Comment: Thank you.  That really helps on what I'm woking on here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's indexing the x/y/z/w components.